# Maven dependency jar version is different from pom.xml specification

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

I keep getting the
**Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\wtpwebapps\WebApp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar**
exception.
I have the dependency version 2.9.6 in my pom.xml file but the jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar in my Maven dependencies folder.

Does anyone know the reason for this or how to solve this?
Why is the jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar there in the first place?

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ipomoea</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
             <version>4.11</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Reference JPA provider, substitute with another JPA provider as desired-->
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FIDO --><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yubico/webauthn-server-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yubico</groupId>
            <artifactId>webauthn-server-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yubico</groupId>
            <artifactId>webauthn-server-attestation</artifactId>
            <!--Check for the latest version at Maven Central-->
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.66</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.upokecenter</groupId>
            <artifactId>cbor</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.checkerframework/checker-qual -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yubico/yubico-util -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yubico</groupId>
            <artifactId>yubico-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.augustcellars.cose/cose-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.augustcellars.cose</groupId>
            <artifactId>cose-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>WebApp</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Maven dependencies folder.... `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using eclipse you can right-click on your project then Maven > Update Project..., then select Force Update of Snapshots/Releases checkbox then click OK.

If you are using Intellij right-click on your project then Maven > Reimport

Eventually you can try through terminal while in the root directory of the project `mvn clean install` or if you have maven wrapper in your project `mvnw clean install` on windows or `./mvnw clean install` on linux.

Comment: The mvn clean install fixed the issue. Thanks